# Concatenate Date and Decimal Time in format mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm format

Tags: excel, loops, datetime, vba

For timings `7:00 AM`; `7:15 AM`,.... `17:00`;`17:15` in rows and date in a Range B6, I am trying to concatenate the values but the value I am getting is in format `02/21/2018 0.29917` format. How can I convert it into format `02/21/2018 7:00` so on...

`c` is time value( `7:00 AM`, `7:15 AM`... `6:00 PM`)

```
For i = 0 To lRow - 1
    c = ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value
    ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = dateofProject & " " & c
Next i
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the time to the date to achieve a datetime.

```
ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).Value = dateofProject + c
```

Format the result cells as `mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm am/pm`.

This assumes that the date is a real date and the times are real times not text-that-looks-like-a-date-or-time.

Comment: Thank you so much ☺

Comment: You could also complete the formatting within the VBA code by adding the following just before Next i: ActiveCell.Offset(i, 0).NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm AM/PM"

Comment: @Thom - Good point. I was thinking it would be best in bulk outside the loop but there was insufficient sample code to offer a solution.